# No output from Halide generator

Tags: c++, c++17, halide

I am trying to follow the tutorial for creating a Halide generator and the executable that is created doesn't produce a halide library when I run it using Windows + MSVC.

I have a simple generator test file:

```
#include "Halide.h"

using namespace Halide;

class TestGen: public Halide::Generator<TestGen>
{
public:
    Input<Buffer<uint8_t, 2>> input{"input"};
    Input<uint8_t> offset{"offset"};

    Output<Buffer<uint8_t, 2>> output{"output"};

    Var x{"x"},y{"y"};

    void generate()
    {
        output(x,y) = input(x, y) + offset;
        output(x,y) = Halide::min(output(x, y), 255.f);

        output.vectorize(x, 16).parallel(y);
    }
};

HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR(TestGen, test_gen);
```

And I compile this along with GenGen.cpp to create the executable called `TestGen.exe`. But when I run this executable with `.\TestGen.exe -g test_gen -o . target=host` it doesn't generate any output library or header and there is no error message (although I don't know if there is error handling).

I have made sure to set the environment variable for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the folder containing my halide.lib and halide.dll. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong

**Edit:** I've just tried adding a print line to the GenGen.cpp file before the generate line to see if it is running at all and it doesn't print it out. Maybe something about the generator build is silently failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your update definition where you are using a float where you should have an int. You should have seen the following error when running `TestGen.exe`:

```
Unhandled exception: Error: In update definition 0 of Func "output":
Tuple element 0 of update definition has type float32, 
but pure definition has type uint8
```

To fix this, you can change

```cpp
output(x,y) = Halide::min(output(x, y), 255.f);
```

to

```cpp
output(x,y) = Halide::min(output(x, y), 255);
```

Note that even after this change, you will get a warning about scheduling:

```
Warning: Update definition 0 of function output has not been scheduled,
even though some other definitions have been. You may have forgotten to
schedule it. If this was intentional, call output.update(0).unscheduled()
to suppress this warning.
```

which you can choose to deal with as you like.

I am not sure why you did not see the original warning or the output from your print statement. It sounds like you might have a problem with your terminal environment or are redirect your output elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I did eventually figure out that it's something to do with CLion's terminal that meant I wasn't getting an output in the end.